# Insert counter for functions in game. (How many times has a function been called throughout the whole run)

Tags: python

```
import random


def first_player_chance():
    p1 = random.randint(1, 10)
    p2 = random.randint(1, 10)
    if p1 != p2:
        print(p1, p2)
        second_player_chance()

    else:
        print(p1, p2)
        return print("First player won!")


def second_player_chance():
    p1 = random.randint(1, 10)
    p2 = random.randint(1, 10)
    if p1 != p2:
        print(p1, p2)
        first_player_chance()

    else:
        print(p1, p2)
        return print("Second player won!")


first_player_chance()
```

This game is a sort of 1 to 10 chance game. If on the first try both get the same number, player one wins. If he doesn't win, player 2 gets a chance. This program works and prints the game with all the tries. But I would like it to output something like: "First player won after X attempts!"

How do I implement a counter in this game? A simple counter += 1 doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple function attribute to achieve it:

```
import random


def first_player_chance():
    first_player_chance.called += 1  # increment called count
    p1 = random.randint(1, 10)
    p2 = random.randint(1, 10)
    if p1 != p2:
        print(p1, p2)
        second_player_chance()
    else:
        print(p1, p2)
        return print(f"First player won after {first_player_chance.called} rounds!")


def second_player_chance():
    second_player_chance.called += 1
    p1 = random.randint(1, 10)
    p2 = random.randint(1, 10)
    if p1 != p2:
        print(p1, p2)
        first_player_chance()

    else:
        print(p1, p2)
        return print(f"Second player won after {second_player_chance.called} rounds!")

first_player_chance.called = 0  # initialize count for the functions
second_player_chance.called = 0

first_player_chance()
```

Which outputs:

```
4 5
5 8
3 1
9 7
10 7
2 1
5 7
5 6
6 2
7 8
4 8
5 6
10 9
3 3
Second player won after 7 rounds!
```

Which is possibly what you're looking for.

Keep in mind that the code can be cleaned up a lot by using a decorator to add the counter instead.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know the .called method! :)

Comment: Functions can have arbitrary attributes just like any class. See: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/What-are-Python-function-attributes

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

count = 0


def first_player_chance():
    global count
    count += 1
    p1 = random.randint(1, 10)
    p2 = random.randint(1, 10)
    if p1 != p2:
        print(p1, p2)
        second_player_chance()

    else:
        print(p1, p2)
        return print("First player won!")


def second_player_chance():
    global count
    count += 1
    p1 = random.randint(1, 10)
    p2 = random.randint(1, 10)
    if p1 != p2:
        print(p1, p2)
        first_player_chance()

    else:
        print(p1, p2)
        return print("Second player won!")


first_player_chance()
print('count: ', count)
```

output:

```
9 8
3 2
1 1
First player won!
count: 3
```

Comment: Oh wow. didn't know you can referr to global variables like that. Nice! Thx!